# Make a Button Visible Conditionally Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am putting a javascript button on a form. The script works, but can I make that button visible only if the DESCRIPTION field starts with a number?

The button gets added to the form and code I could gather is below. That button then calls the function that opens the external url.

```
<push al="center" btnnm="OnBase" col="45" det="DT0" height="1" id="hidden57" keynbr="function=ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument()" nbr="_f292r0" nm="" par="DT0" row="1" sz="8" tooltip="" tp="Hidden"/>


function ShowOnBaseInvoiceDocument0()
{
    var onBaseServer = "someserver";
    var appName = "Dev";
    var screenID = "90";
    var accField = "InvoiceNum";
    var venField = "VendorID";
    var company = Form.getDataValue("TO-COMPANY");
    var RefNums = Form.getDataValue("REFERENCE", 0);
    var RefNum = RefNums.trim();
    var sVenNumbers = Form.getDataValue("DESCRIPTION", 0);
    var sVenNumber = sVenNumbers.substring(0,9);
            
    if (RefNums == "")
    {
        portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox("Not a valid invoice.","ok","info",window,false)
        return true;
    }
        var s = "http://" + encodeURIComponent(onBaseServer) 
        + "/OnBaseLinkScanWeb/AccLogin.aspx?DBID=" + encodeURIComponent(appName) 
        + "&ScreenID=" + encodeURIComponent(screenID) 
        + "&Company=" + encodeURIComponent(company) 
        + "&RefNum=" + encodeURIComponent(RefNum) 
        + "&" + encodeURIComponent(venField) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(portalWnd.strTrim(sVenNumber)); 

      //portalWnd.cmnDlg.messageBox(s,"ok","info",window,false)

      window.open(s, "My Invoice");
      console.log(s);
      return true;
}
```

| Rows Data | Button |
| --- | --- |
| 205121GMAC CASHIERS OF | Button |
| Di Closed Bank 0000 | No Button |
| Close Bank 0073-0000 Al | No Button |

Comment: Why don't you show the relevant code? I cannot spot where the button gets created, and also I don't see the HTML where the button resides.

Comment: if(isNaN(parseInt(description))) hide

Comment: Please provide more relevant code and remove the redundant detail

Comment: @connexo - there is no html code that I have access to. I have the flexibility to modify the delivered form to add javascripts to enhance the delivered form. This is not a deal breaker but I am trying to go above and beyond.

Comment: @connexo - it makes complete sense now that I think more about my question. I see that I showed only the function that is called when the button is pushed but not the button itself. I guess I cant show that because I dont have control over that. Can you mark this question closed?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply loop over all the rows and then check if the first column starts with a Number and if it does not you can simply hide the `button`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(row => {
  const firstCol = row.children[0];
  const secondCol = row.children[1];
  if (!"0123456789".includes(firstCol.innerText[0])) {
    secondCol.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1234567</td>
    <td><button>Click</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HelloWorld</td>
    <td><button>Click</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>245Bye</td>
    <td><button>Click</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Upvote</td>
    <td><button>Click</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer is based on assumptions, which may or may not be true, as OP has not given sufficient information to answer the question without speculating. Also most probably the buttons should be hidden at generation time, not when they are already in the DOM.

Comment: @connexo A downvote was NOT required for that. I was just trying to help.

Comment: Which is exactly the reason for the downvote. Don't attempt to help by answering when the question is completely unclear; instead, try to help OP in comments by asking for missing information.

Comment: To me the question was clear that is why I answered. Anyways will keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: Yes @connexo - you asked for clarification and I provided one.

Comment: @user12938 Did you take a look at my answer?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee - yes. Thank you! I tried to remove the negative vote but it didnt work. I will test your solution. I am sure you saw my note that I dont have preview to the html syntax and I am not sure if this will work. I am under the impression that the back end is xml based. I am being speculative here.